# Download traffic data set from waze or other open traffic data set

Tags: dataset, traffic, waze

I am looking for open traffic data set for my thesis. I know the Waze has good congestion data set, however, my endeavors for finding a way to download its data set was resultless. So, could you please help me how can I access the historical or real-time congestion data?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77122888) answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Just accessing the traffic data of Waze is a bit complicated, but they do offer access to such data through programs like the [Connected Citizens Project](https://www.waze.com/ccp) (though that is aimed more at governments). They also have [a blog](https://data-waze.com/2014/10/02/welcome-to-data-waze/) on which they post all kinds of data analysis results.

On that blog, I see [a post of 2015](https://data-waze.com/2014/10/02/welcome-to-data-waze/) where "traklord" answers a question by asking them to contact him about the idea they're having. I'm not even sure whether he still works for Waze, but I guess it's worth a shot?