# Traffic data from Waze

Tags: waze

On my job we needed the data of traffic or mobility from Waze. In this pandemic I see some study about Covid-19 and in some cases they use Waze databases.
How can I do to have this information?

Answer (score 0):

If by *traffic data* you mean the Waze estimated trip time reachable on [their website live map](https://www.waze.com/live-map), then you can consider [my open-source git repository](https://codeberg.org/Benjamin_Loison/Waze_traffic) enabling you to web-scrape these pieces of information.

For instance it enables as follows displaying with [`matplotlib`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matplotlib) the Waze estimated trip time along the day for a given trip:

[image: matplotlib display of the Waze estimated trip time along the day]